# 4 Friends take a test

Tags: lateral-thinking

4 friends, A, B, C, and D, meet up after taking a test. Reading their results, they exclaimed,

A says, "Hah! I'm ranked 32!"

B says, "I'm ranked 63, better than you, A!"

C says, "I ranked 12, I'm the best!"

D says, "Actually, I'm the best, I scored 142."

**What are A, B, C and D?**

Hint:

> They all took the same test, and the way they represent how they did verbally actually matters.

Hint 2:

> Only D's train of thought is absolutely "correct". Nobody is being deliberately untruthful or deceitful here.

Hint 3:

> D is the only person who interpreted the test score correctly. Think about what kind of test they took!

Note: I'm specifically looking for an answer in the format of:

A is a(n) ______, B is a(n)_____ .....

Comment: Might be kind of troll, but A is a friend, B is a friend, C is a friend, and D is a friend.

Comment: Incorrect. The 4 people each match do a different ____

Comment: @Downvoters reasons? There is a legit answer to this question...

Comment: Does D scoring 142 mean a rank of 142, or was that the actual score in the test?

Comment: @Aify: Human nature.  sigh

Comment: Is "I'm ranked" the same as "I scored" and "I ranked"?

Comment: Literal answer: A is ranked $32!$, which is extremely high. B is ranked $63$, and is better than A. C is ranked $12$. D scored 142 marks, which happens to grant him a better rank ($1$-$11$) than C. *Just kidding! Please clarify your question*.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code Actually this is a valid answer, A is a math freak, B is a gloating (in-your-face) *ss, C is a pompous guy and D is a guy with an above average IQ.

Comment: Why does this continue to get downvoted?

Comment: Added hints to clarify the question.

Comment: (I see how reading back thier results may have caused confusion; i've edited that part for clarity) I can confirm that everything else in the puzzle is **exactly** as it should be.

Comment: When you say "only D is correct" does that mean that A is not ranked 32?

Comment: Grrr if i answer that the problem becomes really obvious... i'll put it in a hint.

Comment: How does Hint 2 Differ from Hint 3?

Comment: Train of thought =/= interpretation of the test results; or rather, all the statements are true as per each participant's interpretation of the result; however, the only person with the correct interpretation was D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shot in the dark:

> A is an imbecile, B is a moron, C is an idiot and D is a superior.

Why?

> According to the [Levine and Marks 1928 IQ classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IQ_classification#Historical_IQ_classification_tables) the only IQ classification that differs such low scores.

Alternatively:

> A, B and C are impaired, and D is a genius according to newer classifications.

Comment: Thumbs up :) Very good shot there.

Comment: @Aify Man, this is so sad :( Great question nonetheless.

Comment: I still don't know why i got downvoted for the question.. I thought it was worded fairly well...

Comment: By the way, what was it that made you take that shot in particular?

Comment: FWIW, a person with an IQ of 12 would probably not be able to communicate like that.

Comment: @Aify sometimes out-of-the-box questions get a bunch of downvotes for no particular reason. IMHO it is a good question, although what thumtackthief says in the comment above is true.

Comment: @Aify Well your "Grrr" comment gave it away.

Comment: @thumbtackthief I hadn't considered that... But then again, if i made it so that he couldn't communicate like that the question would be REALLY obvious...

Comment: Hearing those words like that, "A is an imbecile, B is a moron, C is an idiot" feels like you're just insulting them for being wrong about the order. :(

Comment: Well "historical classifications" of anything always sound kind of insulting.